# Tkinter askcolor returning wrong RGB values?

Tags: python, tkinter, colors

I am using Python 3.6.1.
I need to get a string (or int values) of RGB values of a color chosen with Tkinter askcolor method.
My code:

```
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor

color = askcolor()

rgb_tuple = color[0] #gets tuple of RGB values

color_result_rgb = ' '.join(format(x, "1.0f") for x in rgb_tuple) #tuple into a string
```

Now, say i choose a pink color with values (255, 0, 128)

```
>>> rgb_tuple
```

returns:

```
(255.99609375, 0.0, 128.5)
```

And

```
>>> color_result_rgb
```

returns:

```
'256 0 128'
```

How do I fix this so the returned values are correct?

Comment: Try converting the values to integers, not floats in the `format()` call.

Comment: That is weird; all documentation seems to agree that the return values should *at least* be inside the `0..255` range. None of them specifically mention that a real number (as opposed to the more regular integers) *might* be returned. What OS are you running on? Could there be some color management interfering?

Comment: This looks like a bug - when I run this on my linux box I do indeed get floating point numbers instead of integers. The simple fix is to convert the numbers to int rather than float.

Comment: @martineau: is that a known problem, that converting a value `255` to a float with `format()` yields 255.99-and-a-bit?

Comment: @usr2564301: It's not one I know of—the `255.99609375` _is_ a little strange—but the real problem here is due to converting the results from `askcolor()` to floating point, not integer, format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in tkinter<sup>1</sup>. `askcolor` should be returning integers. The fix seems simple: convert the values to integers before converting them to a string:

```
color_result_rgb = ' '.join(str(int(x)) for x in rgb_tuple)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Looking at the tkinter code, it is indeed intentionally returning a floating point number even though the underlying tcl/tk interpreter is returning an int. This seems like a side effect of the change to the behavior of the `/` operator in python 3.x

This is what the tkinter code is doing to the raw value:

```
r, g, b = widget.winfo_rgb(result)
return (r/256, g/256, b/256), str(result)
```

I've submitted a bug report: [askcolor is returning floats for r,g,b values instead of ints](https://bugs.python.org/issue33289)

Comment: thank you for explaining where the bug comes from. Do I feel silly for not thinking of the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to get the color from the color picker dialog to pass to the create_line method. The askcolor function/method returns ((255.99609375, 0.0, 0.0), '#ff0000'). It's the latter value I need, so these two lines did the trick for me...

```
rgb, color = askcolor()

canvas.create_line((lastx, lasty, event.x, event.y), fill=color)
```